# PowerShell: Add-Member incorrectly changes Objects that aren't the input

Tags: powershell

While doing some testing with `Add-Member`, I created 'copies' of my actual data to test with, but I quickly found that `Add-Member` was actually adding new properties to the original object without being told or asked to. Is this the expected behavior? If yes, how are by reference variables working in PowerShell?

Example:

```
# Create a CSV file
@'
Name,Title
Bob,President
Todd,Secretary
'@ > test.csv

# Load the CSV into an object
$Data = Import-Csv test.csv

# Create a duplicate of $Data (this must be the issue)
$NewData = $Data

# Add a new property to the $NewData object
$NewData | Add-Member ScriptProperty "First Initial" {$this.Name[0]}

# Check the original Object ($Data) and see the madness
$Data

# Viewing $Data as a table
Name Title     First Initial
---- -----     -------------
Bob  President             B
Todd Secretary             T

$Data | Get-Member

# Just confirming that there is indeed a MemberType of ScriptProperty that was added to $Data

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name          MemberType     Definition
----          ----------     ----------
Equals        Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode   Method         int GetHashCode()
GetType       Method         type GetType()
ToString      Method         string ToString()
Name          NoteProperty   string Name=Bob
Title         NoteProperty   string Title=President
First Initial ScriptProperty System.Object First Initial {get=$this.Name[0];}
```

Comment: `PSObject`s are all reference types. Doing deep copies is actually [quite involved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581568/4137916) and to be avoided if there's an alternative (in this case, if your CSV file is not too large, reading it again would do it).

Comment: `$NewData = $Data` does _not_ create a duplicate - both variables refer to the exact same array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out the helpful comments on the question:

`$NewData = $Data` does *not* copy *data*, because `$Data` contains a *reference* to an *array*, which is an instance of a [.NET reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). Instead, it is the *reference* that is copied, so that *both variables end up referencing the very same array*.

An easy (albeit inefficient) way to **create a copy of an array** in PowerShell is to enclose it in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--):

```
# Convenient, but slow with large arrays.
$NewData = @($Data)

# Faster.
$NewData = $Data.Clone()
```

However, if the array's *elements* too contain *references* to .NET reference-type instances, the copied array's elements still reference the very same instances - and the `[pscustomobject]` instances that [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) outputs are indeed reference-type instances.

You can create a copy of the `$Data` array *and* its elements with the following, using the [intrinsic `.psobject` member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) to create (shallow) copies of `[pscustomobject]` instances:

```
$NewData = $Data | ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.Copy() }
```

However, as noted, `.psobject.Copy()` creates a *shallow* copy of each `[pscustomobject]` input object. That is:

- properties that happen to contain instances of [.NET value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) result in true copies in the copied object; similarly, *string* values are *in effect* copies.<sup>[1]</sup>
- by contrast, properties containing references to instances of .NET reference types result in those *references* being copied, which means that both the original object's property value as well as the copied object's point to the very same instance, which means that if the referenced instance is *mutable*, changes to it are reflected in *both* containing objects.

That said, with objects created via [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), whose properties by definition are all *strings*, that is not a concern.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071111/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] `[string]` is technically a *reference* type, but is usually treated like a value type in .NET. Since a string instance is by definition *immutable*, you can rely on any copy of it to remain unchanged. A string can never be *modified*, it can only be replaced by a )new_ string.</sup>

Comment: Stumbled upon a _slightly_ [related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13416651/15243610), but don't see a lot of answers. Based on my newfound understanding of reference types - is it safe to say that [this author's use of `$Script:Result` is unnecessary](https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/02/21/objects-and-hashtables/amp/)? Or are there memory concerns when it comes to passing mutable objects back and forth between functions? At the very end, circa 2013, he notes a concern of passing the hash table itself to functions that update it. That concern doesn't seem valid to me right now

Comment: @immobile2, indeed the use of `$script:` is unnecessary in this case - though you could argue it's better to signal the fact that you're operating on a variable in the script scope explicitly. However, the memory-concern argument suggests a misconception about reference-type instances: It is only the _reference_ to an instance that is passed as an argument, which has a fixed, small size (loosely speaking, a pointer), irrespective of the size of the object it points to.